# Infinite series and the ratio test

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

for the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin^2 (n)}{n^2}$$

which convergence test should i apply , i am thinking the comparison test but then to which series i should compare it to .  The fact that $\sin^2n$ is bounded by 1 and -1 makes me think that we can apply the comparison test

Comment: The question (for positive series) is not "what test shall I use," it is  "does it go down fast enough."

Answer (score 2):

$$\left|\dfrac{\sin^2(n)}{n^2}\right| \leq \dfrac{1}{n^2}$$

then remark that  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2} <+\infty$ (actually it's equal to [$\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem))

Comment: mmm , yes that's right  thanks a lot

Comment: ... and since you mentioned the value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2$, I might also note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin^2(n)/n^2 = (\pi - 1)/2$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks, that completes the answer